# Trying to display my products in my netbeans php project

Tags: php, mysql, netbeans

Products from my MySQL database via phpmyadmin doesn't seem to be displaying on my website. I'm using Netbeans & Wamp

Code: Deals with my images

```
<div class="catalogue_wrapper">
    <div class="catalogue_wrapper_left">
        <?php

            $image = !empty($row['image']) ? 
            $objCatalogue->_path.$row['image'] :
            $objCatalogue->_path.'unavailable.png';

            $width = Helper::getImgSize($image, 0);
            $width = $width > 120 ? 120 : $width;

        ?>
        <a href="?page=catalogue-item&amp;category=<?php echo $category['id']; ?>&amp;id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo Helper::encodeHtml($row['name'], 1); ?>" width="<?php echo $width; ?>" /></a>
    </div>
```

Code: Should display my products

```
<div class="catalogue_wrapper_right">
        <h4><a href="?page=catalogue-item&amp;category=<?php echo $category['id']; ?>&amp;id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo Helper::encodeHtml($row['name'], 1); ?></a></h4>
        <h4>Price: <?php echo Catalogue::$_currency; echo number_format($row['price'], 2); ?></h4>
        <p><?php echo Helper::shortenString(Helper::encodeHtml($row['description'])); ?></p>
        <p><?php echo Basket::activeButton($row['id']); ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everytime I click on a link it displays my error message.

Any help would be appreciated to get these products displaying on my web app.

This is the SQL dump of two tables

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.1.8
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Mar 23, 2014 at 03:06 AM
-- Server version: 5.6.12-log
-- PHP Version: 5.4.16

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `tllecommerce`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `categories`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `categories`
--

INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Liquorice'),
(2, 'Fudge'),
(3, 'Nougat'),
(4, 'Toffee'),
(5, 'Combination'),
(6, 'Allsorts'),
(7, 'Liquorice Straps');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `products`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `category` (`category`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=23 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `products`
--

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `name`, `description`, `price`, `date`, `category`, `image`) VALUES
(1, 'Herbal Liquorice Straps', 'Cut your own straps!\r\n\r\nRolled liquorice sheets flavoured with the popular Chinese herbal extract Glycyrrhiza Glabra. Has the same medicinal and nutritional properties as Herbal Liquorice Bites but a slightly more intense flavour.', '8.00', '2014-03-17 07:59:43', 7, 'Blackstrapszoom.jpg'),
(2, 'Raspberry Sheets', 'Cut your own straps!\r\n\r\nThis is a tasty extrusion of the raspberry log, but with a more intense flavour.', '8.00', '2014-03-17 08:02:17', 7, 'raspberrystrapszoom.jpg'),
(3, 'Chocolate Liquorice Logs', 'Another “best seller”. Similar to the Rasso Choco except that the chocolate centre is wrapped in New Generation''s soft-chew herbal liquorice. \r\n\r\nIf you like liquorice, you will enjoy these. Like the rasso-choco keep it sealed in the fridge. Tip: Cut into short lengths and enjoy with vanilla ice-cream.', '8.00', '2014-03-17 08:05:14', 1, 'chocliqlogZoom.jpg'),
(4, 'Irish Moss Liquorice', 'Not truly a liquorice but a fresh soft jube impregnated with aniseed and covered with colourful hundreds and thousands. Often fought over in a pottle of Allsorts. This item has a long history in confectionery.', '8.00', '2014-03-17 08:08:12', 1, 'irishmosszoom.jpg'),
(5, 'Peaches and Cream Liquorice', 'Slightly piquant, but very pleasant on the palate, this tasty little number is sure to please. \r\n\r\nFlavoured with peach essence and mixed with artificial cream to keep unsaturated fats low, it tastes, as you might expect, of peaches and cream.', '8.00', '2014-03-17 08:09:00', 1, 'peachesNchreamzoom.jpg'),
(6, 'Liquorice Herbal Logs', 'Liquorice logs flavoured this time with something rather different: a popular Chinese herbal extract - Glycyrrhiza Glabra. \r\n\r\nGG runs a close-second to the well-known extract, Ginseng, used in Chinese herbal medicine.', '8.00', '2014-03-17 08:11:14', 1, 'softchewHerbLiqZoom.jpg'),
(7, 'Raspberry Chocolate Liquorice', 'Our ever-popular raspberry-flavoured roll wrapped around crunchy compound chocolate.\r\n\r\nThe cooler it is kept, the crunchier the chocolate becomes. \r\n\r\nIf you freeze it, just suck it until it becomes soft enough to eat. A tasty combination of flavours and textures. Keep the pottle sealed. A favourite with the younger set.', '8.00', '2014-03-17 08:14:00', 1, 'rassochocozoom.jpg'),
(8, 'Assorted Liquorice', 'Individually flavoured, lime, banana, plum and orange cubes in the traditional form: two liquorice and three paste (fruit) layers. Savour each flavour one cube at a time – and return for \r\na different flavour later.', '8.00', '2014-03-17 08:16:02', 6, 'allsortzoom.jpg'),
(9, 'Mini Bag Liquorice Allsorts', 'These versatile little bags are great for fund-raising (schools, clubs), for business promotions and/or give-aways to good customers or to encourage repeat business.\r\n\r\nFor schools & clubs the minimum order is 500 bags; for small businesses 100 bags.\r\n\r\nThe goods have a shelf life of 12 months.', '4.00', '2014-03-17 08:19:00', 6, 'minbag2zoom.jpg'),
(10, 'The Assorted Mini Pottle', 'Fill it with just one liquorice variety or any assortment from within the product range. \r\n\r\nMini pottles are popular in the business community as small give-away gifts of appreciation. A great value-for-money option.', '8.00', '2014-03-17 08:21:00', 6, 'minipottlezoom.gif'),
(11, 'Fruit Mix', 'Mixed fruity liquorice: apricot, blueberry, pineapple, kiwifruit and coconut – a combination you''re unlikely to find anywhere else. \r\n\r\nEach individual allsort contains natural fruit essence and an extra burst of flavour from dried fruit mixed into the paste. A delight for the taste buds.', '8.00', '2014-03-17 08:24:00', 6, 'MixedFruitzoom.jpg'),
(12, 'Chocolate Fudge', 'A chocolate flavoured fudge, light in texture and flavour. \r\n\r\nAnother high-quality NZ product using the best milk products and flavourings.', '8.00', '2014-03-17 08:26:00', 2, 'ChocZoom.jpg'),
(13, 'Liquorice Fudge', 'If you love liquorice this will be for you. Fudge that manages to combine the taste of liquorice with the texture and taste of fudge.', '8.00', '2014-03-17 08:27:00', 2, 'LiquoriceFudgeZoom.jpg'),
(14, 'Russian Fudge', 'A sweet and full-bodied fudge which is neither heavy nor tacky. More-ish. Uses the best available milk products and ingredients. Another long-lasting favourite.', '8.00', '2014-03-17 08:28:00', 2, 'RussianZoom.jpg'),
(15, 'Irish Creme Fudge', 'Lovers of Irish Creme will quickly identify its flavour in this finely textured fudge. \r\n\r\nLight, tasty, satisfying and not cloying. Long-lasting and made with the best ingredients.\r\n', '8.00', '2014-03-17 08:30:00', 2, 'IrishCremeZoom.jpg'),
(16, 'Ginger Liquorice Nougat', 'Added to the NGL mix for lovers of ginger.\r\nCrystallised ginger and liquorice are melted into nougat fresh from the ovens to give a tasty and beautifully balanced treat.\r\n\r\nThe ginger flavour slowly builds on the palate after about 20 seconds but is never too strong. One or two pieces are all you need.\r\n\r\nA great gift for more senior members of the family.', '8.00', '2014-03-17 08:31:00', 3, 'GingerLiqzoom.jpg'),
(17, 'Raspberry Nougat', 'One of our best sellers - pushing the factory into overtime to keep up with demand.\r\n\r\nRaspberry logs are melted into the nougat as soon as it comes from the ovens. If you enjoy a raspberry flavour you''ll certainly like this combination.\r\n\r\nThe product has the same texture as Liquorice Nougat - firm but not chewy.', '8.00', '2014-03-17 08:33:00', 3, 'RaspNougatzoom.jpg'),
(18, 'Pineapple Nougat', 'Promises to be popular! Freshly dried pineapple and pineapple essence give a strong pineapple flavour beautifully balanced by the nougat. \r\n\r\nAnother NZ-made product using the best of ingredients.', '8.00', '2014-03-17 08:34:00', 3, 'PineappleNougatZOOM.jpg'),
(19, 'Liquorice Nougat', 'Eating Ecstasy!\r\n\r\nLike Nougat? Then you''re bound to enjoy this - natural liquorice logs embedded in fresh nougat. \r\n\r\nThe nougat has the same consistency as the liquorice (firm but not chewy) and the two flavours are a unique blend.', '8.00', '2014-03-17 08:36:00', 3, 'LiqNougatzoom.jpg'),
(20, 'Toffee', 'Something different...\r\n\r\nThis is a rather soft chewing lolly with the liquorice and aniseed combining to produce subtle flavours. \r\n\r\nIndividually wrapped.', '8.00', '2014-03-17 08:38:00', 4, 'toffeeZoom.jpg'),
(21, 'Liquorice Combo', '700 grams of liquorice combination', '15.00', '2014-03-17 08:40:00', 5, NULL),
(22, 'Nougat Combo', '700 grams of nougat combination', '15.00', '2014-03-17 08:41:00', 5, NULL);

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `products`
--
ALTER TABLE `products`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `products_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`category`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: what is the error message? where is the query?

Comment: Error Message: <br/> `} else {
?>
<p>There are no products in this category.</p>
<?php  
  }
  require_once("_footer.php");
 `

Comment: You need to check your query.

Comment: Queries are in my catalogue class: public function getProducts($cat) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `{$this->_table_2}`
                                WHERE `category` = '".$this->db->escape($cat)."'
    ORDER BY `date` DESC";
                
  return $this->db->fetchAll($sql);
 }

Comment: Did you run this query in phpmyadmin and got results?

Comment: How do I do that? Do I copy and paste the function into the query section of my database? If so nothing happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this query in phpMyAdmin and check if you are getting any results against it, if not then it means no product exist in your database that belongs to the category you are trying to fetch

```
$table1 = "products" ;
$table2 = "categories" ;

SELECT * FROM $table1 LEFT JOIN $table2 ON $table2.`category` = $table1.`id` WHERE $table1.`category` = $cat ORDER BY $table1.`date` DESC
```

Comment: Empty result! My sql statements are way off 'category' is a column in 'your_table_name' I need to match it with a column in another table. I'm not sure how to write this. Would it be: SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = categories.id ORDER BY date DESC?

Comment: do you have two tables which you are trying to `JOIN`? how are both tables connected?

Comment: Im using these variables to identify both tables `private $_table = 'categories'; private $_table_2 = 'products';`

Comment: What is a common column in both tables

Comment: category column in products table and id column in categories table

Comment: try the updated query above, is your column `category` in categories table?

Comment: There is data in my tables but the query above returns `MySQL returned an empty result set` No `category column` is in the `products table`, the products are assigned to a category number that matches the `id column` in the `categories table`

Comment: The queries seem to be working but it's returning a empty result set.

Comment: i need more details then, perhaps a dump of both tables so i can see why it not pulling the records

Comment: try my updated query above, i ran it and it seems to be giving me 4 products `Assorted Liquorice`, `Mini Bag Liquorice Allsorts`, `The Assorted Mini Pottle` and `Fruit Mix`

Comment: I altered your query so it would display everything. Removed the 6 and replaced it with products category column. `SELECT * FROM products LEFT JOIN categories ON``products.``category`` = categories.``id` `WHERE``categories.``id``= products.``category`

Comment: @newPHPer no you did not. Don't do that. It's not your answer to mess and deface.

Comment: Roger that @Shadow Wizard

Comment: @newPHPer The query I gave you in answer above should work fine as i am getting the results

Comment: Yes! It displays results. My current function looks like this: > >   private $_table = 'categories';
>    private $_table_2 = 'products';
>    public function getProducts($cat) {
>    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `{$this->_table_2}`
>    WHERE `category` = '".$this->db->escape($cat)."'
>    ORDER BY `date` DESC";                  
>    return $this->db->fetchAll($sql);
>    } How would I translate your new query to fit within this function?

Comment: try the updated query above, if you are starting out on PHP, it might be a good idea to look into PDO (http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) as it is alot safer

Comment: Thanks for your time and help @Baig I will read up on that article and do more research on how to write these queries. Thanks again!

Comment: no problem, if my answer was helpful and if it did solve your problem please do not forget to mark the anwer